# React router V5 : 'react-router-dom' does not contain an export named 'useHistory'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I was using useHistory which is provided by router-dom from version 5 and above.
It was working fine until I started getting this error, I tried searching for solutions but couldn't get it. Any help is appreciated.Below is the chunk of code where I used the useHistory.

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./HomePage.css";
import Card from "../../Components/Card/Card";
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const HomePage = props => {
const history = useHistory();
```

//some code goes here where the value of ele is assigned based on some logic

```
const goTo = ele => {
    switch (ele) {
      case "C":
        history.push("/Page1");
        break;
      case "R":
        history.push("/Page2");
        break;
      case "E":
        history.push("/Page3");
        break;
      case "D":
        history.push("/Page4");
        break;
      case "I":
        history.push("/Page5");
        break;
      case "T":
        history.push("/Page4");
        break;
      default:
        history.push("/");
    }
  };
```

Comment: What changed in your project or environment when it stopped working? Does re-running `npm i` re-install the dependencies?

Comment: Nothing is changed, I never touched Homepage component after it was working fine. I restart the server today and boom I'm getting this. I even reinstalled the dependecies but no use.